# Angular: Change in Pipe not detected

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have this pipe which multiplies the **input** value by an other value retrieved from a service:

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'multiply'
})
export class MultiplyPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private service: StateService) { }

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return value * this.service.multiplier;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
{{ value | multiply }}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-detectchanges?file=app%2Fmultiply.pipe.ts)

This works fine, but when the `multiply` value from the service is changed, it doesn't trigger any change detection, and thus

```
 {{ value | multiply }}
```

is not run again, leaving the old value on the screen. Any suggestion how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As discussed in [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pipes-and-change-detection), and as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-detectchanges-sbocpk), one way to force the pipe to be called is to make it impure:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'multiply',
  pure: false
})
```

For more details about pure and impure pipes, you can see [this article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-essential-difference-between-pure-and-impure-pipes-and-why-that-matters-999818aa068).

Comment: pain when you don't know it)

Comment: Worked for me ... many thanks, was driving me insane!!

Answer (score 6):

I believe the issue is that while the component receives events if it accesses `StateService`, the pipe does not.

To fix this, instead change `MultiplyPipe` to take a `multiplier` argument, instead of trying to access `StateService`:

```
transform(value: any, multiplier: any): any {
  return value * multiplier;
}
```

Then have `hello.component` access `StateService`, and pass in the value of `multiplier` as an argument to the pipe:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { StateService } from './state.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Value = {{value | multiply: this.service.multiplier}}</h1>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  value = 10;

  constructor(private service: StateService) {}
```

Working example here: [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-detectchanges-2jauhu)